# Why can't lex recognize my regular expression definitions

Tags: c, lex

I was doing it as:

```
    /* regular definitions */

    DECLARATIONS                declarations
    ENDDECLARATIONS         (enddeclarations)
    INT                     (int)
    METHOD                  (method)
    PROGRAM                 (program)
```

And

```
    {DECLARATIONS}          {yycolumn+=yyleng;return (DECLARATIONSnum);}
```

to recognize it, but I found out that they were not recognized..... And if I do it like:

```
    "declarations"          {yycolumn+=yyleng;return (DECLARATIONSnum);}
```

It worked. I really can't understand why....

The sample input is like:

```
   program p2;
   class Test {
    method void main()
     declarations
        int x;
```

And currently it is like:

```
    program p2
    5       1         SEMInum
    class Test 
    6       1         LBRACEnum
    method void main
    7       1         LPARENnum
```

the program, class should be recognized as a Reserved word, but they are not recognized....

Comment: What version of lex are you using?  Provide a complete .l file that demonstrates the problem -- when I build one from your fragments it works just fine, recognizing the keywords regardless of which form they're in.

Comment: @ChrisDodd  It is lex version 2.5.4. The whole file is a little bit too long...Is there a possibility that this error comes from the version?

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARATION             declarations
```

Singular

```
{DECLARATIONS}          {yycolumn+=yyleng;return (DECLARATIONSnum);}
```

Plural

Comment: Thanks, but actually it seems not the critical problem, actually it cannot recognize any of these definitions... And for "declaration" tag, it still does not work after I make the plural right

Comment: Do you mean for the parens to be part of the pattern? If so they should be in quotes, if not there doesn't seem to be a reason for them.

Comment: Please show us a sample of what input you're using, how you expect it to be parsed, and how it's being parsed.

Comment: I have reedited the problem, the current problem is that it cannot recognize those written in this way   {DECLARATIONS}